# How can i get user Device Id in iOS?

Tags: ios, iphone

I want the device id of user mobile bcz I want to store it in database while submitting the form,so that whenever user uninstall the app and again reinstall the same at that time he will get all record which is submitted previously so he need not to submit the data again.I used library but it will return the same id for all device.please help.Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is no longer possible. Apple disabled it in iOS 7 (I think) to avoid ad agencies tracking users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Official Documentation answer

@property(nonatomic, readonly, retain) NSUUID *identifierForVendor

```
NSString *identifier = [[UIDevice currentDevice].identifierForVendor UUIDString];
```

The value of this property is the same for apps that come from the same vendor running on the same device. A different value is returned for apps on the same device that come from different vendors, and for apps on different devices regardless of vendor.

Normally, the vendor is determined by data provided by the App Store. If the app was not installed from the app store (such as enterprise apps and apps still in development), then a vendor identifier is calculated based on the app’s bundle ID. The bundle ID is assumed to be in reverse-DNS format.

On iOS 6, the first two components of the bundle ID are used to generate the vendor ID. if the bundle ID only has a single component, then the entire bundle ID is used.

On IOS 7, all components of the bundle except for the last component are used to generate the vendor ID. If the bundle ID only has a single component, then the entire bundle ID is used.

If the value is nil, wait and get the value again later. This happens, for example, after the device has been restarted but before the user has unlocked the device.

**The value in this property remains the same while the app (or another app from the same vendor) is installed on the iOS device.** **The value changes when the user deletes all of that vendor’s apps from the device and subsequently reinstalls one or more of them.** The value can also change when installing test builds using Xcode or when installing an app on a device using ad-hoc distribution. Therefore, if your app stores the value of this property anywhere, you should gracefully handle situations where the identifier changes.

Comment: Is there any other solution for my question? I want the solution that is compatible for all device and is there any library for that than please let me know.thanks

Answer (score 1):

you can use unique device id  FOR IOS6+

```
NSString *identifier = [[UIDevice currentDevice].identifierForVendor UUIDString];
```